# WPF End-User Toolbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on a product in WPF that requires an end-user toolbox, exactly like Visual Studio, where the user can drag and drop specific tools (such as a `Button`) onto another `Canvas` object.

So far, I have it looking OK, and am using the official Microsoft `vector icons` next to a `label` describing the tool.

For example, the code below displays a `vector button icon` and a `label` next to it.

My question is, how do I group both the `image` and `label` together so that they are "one item", similar to the Visual Studio toolbox.

I need the two grouped items to be draggable/droppable onto a separate `Canvas` object.

I don't have much experience with this in WPF so any advice would be appreciated.

```
    <Viewbox
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        Width="16"
        Height="16"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="0">
        <Rectangle
            Width="16"
            Height="16">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <DrawingBrush>
                    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                        <DrawingGroup>
                            <GeometryDrawing
                                Brush="#00FFFFFF"
                                Geometry="F1M16,16L0,16 0,0 16,0z" />
                            <GeometryDrawing
                                Brush="#FFF6F6F6"
                                Geometry="F1M2.5857,-0.000199999999999534L-0.000299999999999745,2.5858 -0.000299999999999745,9.4138 2.5857,12.0008 7.9997,12.0008 7.9997,14.2418 9.4317,14.2418 10.3357,13.2478 11.2607,15.3318 14.2687,13.9638 13.4017,11.9978 15.3537,11.9978 15.3537,10.5318 15.1097,10.3048 16.0007,9.4138 16.0007,2.5858 13.4147,-0.000199999999999534z" />
                            <GeometryDrawing
                                Brush="#FF424242"
                                Geometry="F1M9,6L9,13.23 10.629,11.441 11.766,14.004 12.955,13.463 11.869,10.998 14.387,10.998z M8,11L3,11 1,9 1,3 3,1 13,1 15,3 15,9 14.376,9.624 13.642,8.943 14,8.586 14,3.414 12.586,2 3.414,2 2,3.414 2,8.586 3.414,10 8,10z" />
                            <GeometryDrawing
                                Brush="#FFF0EFF1"
                                Geometry="F1M8,10L3.414,10 2,8.586 2,3.414 3.414,2 12.586,2 14,3.414 14,8.586 13.642,8.943 8,3.708z" />
                        </DrawingGroup>
                    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                </DrawingBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
    </Viewbox>

    <Label
        Content="Button"
        Grid.Row="1"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        Margin="29,0,2.6,0.4" />
```

Comment: So ... what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Manfred I posted my code, I am not familiar with how to group these controls into a single "unit" that can not only be highlighted on mouseover, like the VS toolbox, but also dragged/dropped.  I can read about the drag/drop techniques and associated mouse events, but I don't know what WPF control groups these two into a logical unit.

Comment: In WPF any kind of Panel or Container would be suitable for that: Grid, Canvas, DockPanel, StackPanel, a UserControl or custom Control, etc.